# Change motherboard with exact same model

Tags: windows-10, motherboard

The audio of my **Asrock z87 pro4** died unexpectedly. Fortunately it's still in warranty so they send me the exact same model of mine.
Do you think I will have any problems with **Windows 10**?
 Do I will need to reinstall?

Comment: Reinstall, no. Reactivate, maybe. At worst you'll need to make sure your boot options match such as whether it boots as UEFI or BIOS/CSM.

Comment: It's uefi, but it's the stock option.

Comment: As the driver is already installed and it is the same device, I think they should be no problem at all.

Comment: Since your Windows 10 license is a retail license, based on the motherboard you had, activation shouldn't be a problem.  If Window doesn't activate a call to the Microsoft Activation Center will be required.

Comment: @Ramhound my license is from windows 7 and upgraded to w10 for free

Comment: @Kreker - You still have transfer rights because your Windows 7 license had transfer rights.  Microsoft might not advertise that fact, but in my research, I have found more then enough evidence to conclude that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** You do not have to reinstall. In fact, you will be able to continue normally.

**Long answer:** Traditionally, changing motherboard has always been one of the things that voided Windows activation. However, you need not worry, for the following reasons:

- Windows might not considers the replacement of the motherboard with an exact same model a *motherboard change*. It entirely depends on the manufacturer and intricate manufacturing details that we don't know. (For example, what if the manufacturer sends a motherboard with updated BIOS or a different serial number?) Also, Windows 10 is a much more tolerant and lenient Windows.
- You can prevent the activation getting voided by associating your Windows 10 license with your Microsoft account. Either sign in to Windows using a Microsoft account, or use the Settings app to link the license. For detailed information, see:

  1. ["How to associate your Windows 10 license with a Microsoft account"](https://www.onmsft.com/news/how-to-associate-your-windows-10-license-with-a-microsoft-account). *On MSFT*. 15 October 2016. (Explains how to sign in using a Microsoft account, which automatically links Windows license with the account.)
  2. ["Reactivating Windows 10 after a hardware change"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20530/windows-10-reactivating-after-hardware-change). *Support*. Microsoft. 1 September 2016. (Explains how to (1) link a Windows license to a Microsoft account without signing in with one, and (2) how to recover that license.)
- On previous versions of Windows, such as Windows 7, people could contact Microsoft support, explain their case, and get their Windows reactivated while continuing to work unhindered during the 30-day grace period. Replacing a damaged motherboard with the exact same model has always been good enough for Microsoft to warrant reactivation.

In any case, you can most likely continue working unhindered.

**Before changing your motherboard, make sure you do a full shutdown. To do so, hold down the Shift key before clicking on the shutdown button.**

Comment: My license is from a windows 7, upgraded free to windows 10. I have already using a microsoft account I think for using onedrive, is this correct? in the windows login prompt I have the email of msn account and a pin I set. Am I able?

Comment: @Kreker Yes. You seem to be all set.

Comment: Ok, I'll try when thw motherboard arrive and I'll let you know! Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that the operation's gone straight without an hassle. No need to reactivate or nothing.Many thanks, answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

My activation for Windows 10 Pro still works for HP Compaq Pro 6300 SFF because I had the same computer motherboard and same model as what I have now the only difference is my original machine still runs 20H1 not 22H2 the only problem it has is the power fan needs to be cleaned

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Drivers will work but some hardware IDs will not match. Windows should be able to refresh that, but your license will not work anymore.